# Confusion about connection/symbol to air-flow switch

Tags: sensor, symbol

I am interested in using an air-flow dependent switch. Luckily, they make those:

http://www.spx.com/nl/assets/pdf/SPX_LS_and_FS_Series_en.pdf

Unfortunately the pinout/internal circuit is not very clear to me, and the documentation doesn't explicitly spell it out:

[image]

As I understand from reading the documentation, I need to apply a voltage to the "heater" which heats up an internal thermal element. If the element gets too hot (ie there is no airflow cooling it down), a switch will either open or close (depending on the part number).

Which pins are the heater, and which pins are the switch? I think pin 5 looks the most similar to a relay contact symbol, but then again the symbol between pin 2 and 3 looks like a bimetallic contactor which are also used as thermal-switches.

Any help?

Comment: Heater looks like p1 to p4 and this is what happens when an HVAC draftsman does an electromechanical schematic.  Send a letter to supplier or better, call them for the App Note. There are too many options for V in this 5W thermal switch. Fujitsu just used a heater 2W resistor and reed type relay next to fan, another option is PTC polyfuse for fan fail with a 85'C threshold at rated current in ambient convection or some thermistor with R ref. to a transistor switch.

Comment: 2 & 3 are also the symbol for a thermal overload relay.

Comment: They do have technical support numbers.

Comment: Got to love  *Setting: Per table, Page 12* on a 6 page document....

Answer (score 1):

Contacted technical support for clarification. Assuming he knew what he was talking about: Pins 2 and 3 are the heater. Pin 5 to 7 is the switch, and 1, 4, 6, 7 are electrically connected.